# Prevent apps being uninstalled

Tags: applications, uninstallation

My kids love playing with my Android. However, they don't always understand what they are doing, and occasionally I find that they have deleted some of my apps (strangely, never the ones they play).

Is there any app that can make uninstall more difficult, or make access to the apps menu more difficult (e.g. require a password)?

Comment: I think that your question is covering the same ground as this previous one about locking the Application Settings menu http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7117/i-want-to-password-lock-my-applications-settings-but-no-other-settings if you want something more general to lock certain apps, see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [Smart App Protector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free) with its helper app (for enhanced reliability). Make sure to make it device administrator. Then, lock `Package Installer` and `Play Store` using it (lock down other market apps too). With one tap, the app can lock all apps which could uninstall it. The app facilitates this for its own security, but its solution of your question.

And, I can bet... after that your kids can't uninstall an app without developer level expertise.

**Update:**
After your comment, looks like your app launcher is capable of uninstalling apps directly like Play Store. So, lock your Launcher too. From your screenshot, its Samsung TouchWhiz launcher having package name `tw.launcher`. Lock this package with Smart App Protector. But, it'd lock your app drawer too.
If you don't want to lock your app drawer, best way is to switch your [Home Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Home%20Launcher&so=1&c=apps) app & lock `Package Installer`, `Play Store` etc. Done!
Alternate launcher apps have more features as well as memory efficiency. So, its better in all other aspects. If you don't want to spend money, I'd recommend you [Go Launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex). If you can spend money for this, I'd recommend you [ADW Launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adwfreak.launcher).

Comment: This is the essentially the same as GAThrawn's and it fails exactly the same way

Comment: @Shahar Not exactly same.. I've targeted `Package Installer`. Can you tell me how exactly it fails?

Comment: Looks like you are saying it without trying.. One thing, I want to clear: As long as your device is open for installation, you can't disable uninstallation natively. Locking is the only way!

Comment: I don't know what it looks like. I installed your app, locked the Package Installer and Play Store. Then I went to the menu and deleted applications with nothing stopping me from doing it.

Comment: @Shahar Menu? What type of menu? Can you elaborate your steps? I am now getting feeling that you're talking about removing icons from homescreen..

Comment: This menu [link](http://static.stuff.co.nz/1287042945/188/4235188.jpg). When I press the menu button on the bottom left, the application items shown have a little minus sign on them, and pressing them deletes them from the phone.

Comment: @Shahar Tapping that minus sign should redirect to `package installer` for uninstallation. But, if its uninstalling directly, see my answer update..

Comment: Yes, it's uninstalling directly. In Smart App Protector, I don't the option to lock packages, only applications.

Comment: @Shahar That's the same thing in this aspect. Its a system app.. Look for Launcher or TwLauncher name. The name generally contains Launcher word..

Comment: Finally found it, and it works. I'm fine with locking the app drawer. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3057/discussion-between-shahar-and-sachin-shekhar)

Comment: What does "make it device administrator" in your first paragraph mean? I'm looking at info on an app (Android 4.3) and see buttons to Force stop, uninstall and clear data, but nothing about being admin or not. Thanks!

Comment: @DarrenCook Go to `Device Administrators` from `Settings` ~> `Security`..

Answer (score 7):

There are quite a few apps in the Market which will lock certain apps behind a password, a search in the Market for "[applock](https://market.android.com/search?q=applock&so=1&c=apps)" should find most of them.

I haven't actually used any, so can't give you a recommendation, but these should allow you to lock the Market and Settings apps behind a PIN number, to keep your kids out of them.

Comment: From what I can see, the applock apps prevent unauthorized running of the applications. This is not what I'm looking for. I want to prevent my kids from uninstalling applications, not running them.

Comment: @Shahar if you set the app to lock the Market app and the Settings app, then your kids shouldn't be able to uninstall any apps, no need to lock anything else if you don't want to.

Comment: I tried a couple of these apps, but even after locking the Market and Settings apps, I was able to both enter the menu and uninstall applications, with no lock screen shown in the process.