# Is there a way to prevent a user from deleting apps on android?

Tags: uninstallation

Suppose I install app X for purpose A. I don't want to simply be able to uninstall the app. How do I prevent myself from uninstalling an app on android?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/prevent-apps-being-uninstalled

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest installing [Smart AppLock (App Protector)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free). You can password protect apps from being uninstalled using this app.

Comment: This can work, however, note that androidgy wants to prevent himself from uninstalling apps. That means you will have to get somebody else to create the password for the Applock app, otherwise you could just disable Applock at any time. Also, with this method you actually lock the Package Installer, which prevents you from uninstalling ALL apps.

Answer (score 1):

Root that device and move that app to /system/app

Comment: Instructions please