# Drag-n-drop Uninstall

Tags: settings, uninstallation

I have a Moro G5 and would like to know if there is any way I can disable the Android drag-n-drop Uninstall feature from the homepage which allows little fingers to uninstall parental apps by just dragging the appropriate icon to the uninstall at the top of the screen.

At times it makes me wonder why Android has this feature. Is it a life and death situation that requires apps to be uninstalled so easily?

I've tried to install different apps which claim to prevent uninstalling of apps but all fail and again uninstalling anything is as simple as dragging an icon to the uninstall.

Comment: just don't leave your child unattended, it's not a healthy toy

Comment: There are four different answers to this question at this link. [Prevent apps being uninstalled](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/prevent-apps-being-uninstalled)